# Identifying files being actively written to CIFS share

Tags: linux, samba, cifs, find

Is there a way to identify files that are actively being written to a CIFS mount in Linux?   I am interested in skipping those files.

My first thought would be to fine tune the find command with mmin.   I am not sure if this would catch them though.

```
find /cifs -type f -name "*.wav" -mmin +3
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the smbstatus command.

There you could grep for READ/WRITE locks (e.g.)

```
smbstatus  | grep RDWR
```

Add sed or awk magick to get to the file name.

Comment: So I should clarify that a different server is writing these files to the share

Comment: you could still use smbstatus over ssh, (from the writing server): `ssh <server with smb share> smbstatus | grep RDWR`
Of course you need to set up authentication by ssh key pair.

Comment: I don't have access to the servers writing to the share